# Will passing a reference to the very object you're using .bind on cause a circular reference

Tags: jquery, circular-reference

I have a jQuery object, and I'm using `.bind()` method to assign an event to that object. However I'm also passing a reference to the object itself to the bind method as well like so:

```
$( document ).ready(function ()
{
    // Grab the jQuery version of the DOM element.
    var $formField1 = $( "#form-field-1" );
    // I should probably store this stuff in $formField1.data(),
    //  but not until I find out if this can cause a circular reference.
    var formFields = {
        "jQ": $formField1,
        "$comment": $( "#form-field-1-comment" ),
        "commentAnswers": [ 2, 4 ]
    };
    // Set up the comment to show when a certain answer is given.
    this.jQ.bind( "change", formFields, toggleComment );
});

function toggleComment( p_event )
{
    // Show/hide comments based on the answer in the commentAnswers array.
    if ( $.inArray($(this).val(), question.commentAnswers) > -1 )
    {
        question.$comment.parent().slideDown();
    }
    else
    {
        question.$comment.parent().slideUp();
    }
}
```

I want to know if this will "in fact" cause a circular reference?

Comment: What is `this.jQ`?  Don't you mean `formFields.jQ`?  In which case, just use `$formField1`.

Comment: In the original code there is a $.each loop performed on all the form field in a form. I wanted to exclude code that wasn't relevant and I just missed changing this to $formField1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not a circular reference, but it is redundant. The object triggering the event will be available through `this` inside the event handler. It's not necessary to pass it in.

However, it's important to realize that the data passed into `bind` when it's set is static. Whereas, `this` inside the event handler will always store the particular object that triggered the event. Those two objects may be the same or they may be different, depending on how widely the `bind` is applied.

Comment: I figured out this morning that it was redundant, and had I just attached commentAnswers and $comment to the object itself using .data() method, then this whole question would have been avoided. Still the answer is important to know. And thanks!

Comment: I almost had an anxiety attack from the thought that it could be a circular reference.